# "com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Can't co-create object" with java 11

Tags: java

Im working with SAP test automation with the `JCOB` DLL 1.18.64bit library.
My code was working fine when I run the test with Java 8.
But when I set the project settings to Java 11, I got below error.

```
com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Can't co-create object
```

Is there any specific `JCOB` version available for Java 11?

Answer (score 0):

I used the below link to download 32 bit version of java latest and use that in my test.And it was working fine now.

```
https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/?variant=openjdk11
```